# Alining 'semi-triangular' commutative diagram

Tags: diagrams, commutative-diagrams

I'm trying to draw a commutative diagram of the this figure: [image]

But the best I can do is with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=5em]
     & U \arrow[r, "i"] & V \arrow[r, "T"] \arrow[dr, "\pi"] & W & \\
                     &&V/U \arrow[ur, "\tilde{T}"] \\ 
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

How would I get my code to mimic my diagram? I would like to get the V/U to be aligned with the "T" of the arrow from V to W. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding an extra empty cell between V and W, and by skipping this cell for the arrow from V to W with the direction `rr` (twice right). The node V/U can go in this cell on the second row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=5em]
U \arrow[r, "i"] & V \arrow[rr, "T"] \arrow[dr, "\pi"] &                             & W \\
                 &                                     & V/U \arrow[ur, "\tilde{T}"] & \\ 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get equal width of the top arrows (taking into account the widths of the objects):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={3em,between origins}]
U \arrow[rr, "i"] && V \arrow[rr, "T"] \arrow[rd, "\pi\vphantom{\tilde{T}}"] && W \\
& &&V/U \arrow[ru, "\tilde{T}"]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, also a shorter arrow from *U* might be considered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={4em,between origins}]
U \arrow[r, "i"] & V \arrow[rr, "T"] \arrow[rd, "\pi\vphantom{\tilde{T}}"] && W \\
 &&V/U \arrow[ru, "\tilde{T}"]  
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My version of 'semi-triangular' commutative diagram.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=15pt]
U \arrow[r, "i"] &[3em] V \arrow[rr, "T"] \arrow[rd, "\pi"] & &W \\
&&V/U \arrow[ru, "\tilde{T}"] &  
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]